# What's the one liner to split a string to dictionary with default value in python3?

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary

I have a input string `input_str = 'a=1;b=2;c'` and I want to split it into dictionary as `{'a':1, 'b':2, 'c': '.'}`

```
input_str = 'a=1;b=2;c'
default = '.'
output = dict(s.split('=') if '=' in s else {s ,default} for s in input_str.split(';'))

print(output)
{'a': '1', 'b': '2', '.': 'c'}

# Output I want:
{'a': '1', 'b': '2', 'c': '.'}
```

Following code works.But I was looking for a one liner with dict comprehension.

```py
my_result = {}
input_str = 'a=1;b=2;c'
for s in input_str.split(';'):
    if '=' in s:
        key, val = s.split('=')
        my_result[key] = val
    else:
        my_result[s] = '.'
```

I noticed that else condition in above code `{s ,default}` is treated as set. How to convert it into dictionary.

Comment: It *is* a set, that's why. The dict constructor accepts a sequence of *pairs*; order matters here, so try a tuple `(s, default)`.

Answer (score 1):

As you noted, `{s, default}` defines a set, and the order of sets is undefined.

All you need to do to remedy this is to use a list instead.

```
dict(s.split('=', 1) if '=' in s else [s, default] for s in input_str.split(';'))
```

Note, this is unlikely to be very useful in real-life unless you have very restricted requirements.  What happens if you want to include a value that contains a ';' character?

By changing the first split() call to have `, 1`, this means that the value will only ever be split once, no matter how many '=' characters there are.

For example, trying to parse an input of: `a=bad=value;b=2` would raise a ValueError.